# NQueen algorithm: my python dose not respond in my code (in variable "y")

Tags: python, algorithm

I have tried to do NQueen algorithm.

When I call dictionary "y" in "y.values()" my python does not respond.
but if I input "x" in "x.values()" it's work.

It seems like my "y" is NULL when I print it in checker() function.
My "y" should be:

```
{0: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 2}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 1}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 3}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 7}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 1}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 1, 5: 3}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 1, 5: 3, 6: 5}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 7}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 6}
{0: 0, 1: 4}
{0: 2}
{0: 2, 1: 0}
{0: 2, 1: 4}
```

here is my code:

```
from math import *

N=8
#row = [0 for i in range(N)]
#row=[]
row={}
x={}
y={}

def checker(r,c):
    #print(y)
    if c in ( x.values() ):
        return False
    elif x:
        dia=0
        while dia < r:
            if abs(row[dia] - c) == abs(dia - r):
                return False
            dia+=1

    return True



def nqueen(ir):
    if ir>N-1: #(ir>N-1):
        print(row)
    else:
        for col in range(N):
            row[ir] =  col

            if (checker(ir,col)):
                x[ir] = col
                y = dict( (k, x[k]) for k in (range(ir+1)) )
                print(y)
                nqueen(ir+1)

nqueen(0)
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: the `y` that you edit in `nqueen` is not the `y` in the global namespace. You can make them the same by writing `global y` at the top of `nqueen`. Even better would be to explicitly return and pass in any variables you need like `y`.